# Python: Creating time series with multiple channels for ConvNet

Tags: python, neural-network, time-series, conv-neural-network

I am using Convolutional Networks to work with forecasting time series. For this I am using rolling windows to take the last t points to use them as time series. Every feature is going to be a channel,so I have a multiple time series set. The data need to be in 3 dimensions [n_samples,window_size,features]. The original data set I have is [n_samples,features]. The data is already in time ascending order. My problem is that the way I am creating my 3D tensor crash my computer, given I have close to 500k rows. This is the code I am using.

```
prueba = x_data # This data set has shape [500k,20]
window_size = 100 # I taking the last 100 days
n_units,n_features = prueba.shape
n_samples = n_units - window_size +1 # Represent the number of samples you are getting from the rolling windows.
data_list = []

for init_index in range(n_samples):

    fin_index = window_size + init_index
    window_set = prueba[init_index:fin_index,:]
    window_flat = np.reshape(window_set,(1,window_size*n_features))
    data_list.append(window_flat)

features_tensor = np.concatenate(data_list,axis = 0)
features_tensor = np.reshape(features_tensor,(n_samples,window_size,n_features)) ## This break my computer
```

The problem is that my computer crashes when I use np.concatenate to put together all the individual data set I create. Does anyone know faster way to this. I am trying to think in a way to avoid using np.concatenate, but so far I havent been able to figure out.

Comment: if you're crashing due to using up all your RAM, then consider dumping the data into .npy files or a database to store results into disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the approach you have here (which results in `np.concatenate`) is quite inefficient, since you are duplicating every data point (roughly) `window_size` times.  And that is almost certainly a waste of memory, since whatever operation that acts on this dataset should, ideally, be able to do it on a rolling basis: go through the time series without having to see the fully expanded / vastly duplicated dataset in tensor format.

**So, I suggest that the better approach is to find a way to avoid building this redundant tensor in the first place.**

Since we don't know what you are doing with this tensor, it's not possible to give an answer.  However, here are a few things to consider:

1. One "right" way to do this is to use `pandas`, which has a rolling window feature `df.rolling()`[docs here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html).  This does exactly what you want (performs computations on a rolling window, without a big redundant tensor), but of course only if that works with the downstream code.
2. If you are using `tensorflow`, then you'll be better served by creating a generator to `yield` the window when called, which can be put into a `tf.Dataset` (see the `.from_generator()` method and example [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset)).
3. In Keras, try `TimeseriesGenerator`, which has this capability.  [docs here](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/)

Comment: I am using this tensor as the input of my ConvNet. I have an architecture in Keras  and I want to read the input with the format [n_samples,window_size,features] so I can feed it as the input in the model. Thats why I want to have the complete tensor. I will look into the suggestion you gave me.

Comment: ok, in keras, try `TimeseriesGenerator`.  It's the same generator answer I gave above, but for keras instead of tf.  Point is, no need to actually create that big tensor.  I'll edit my answer with a link.